# "You are your self first supporter", a more proper way to say it

Tags: phrases, idiomatic-language

I want to say that the person himself/herself should be the first supporter of himself/herself. I came up with two different ways of saying that, and I want to know if they are all correct, and which one presents the best version.

> 1. You are your self first supporter.
> 2. You are the first supporter for yourself.

I prefer the first one as it sounds idiomatic, but I don't want the "your self" part to get confused with "yourself" when spoken loudly. So is there another word I can substitute "self" with?

---

P.S.

I want "support" to be about all the psychological aspects of the human being, not financial support for example. In other words, you would say that phrase to encourage someone in achieving his/her dreams and goals, to keep fighting in life (not literally), to overcome challenges, and so on.

By "first" I mean that you should support yourself **before** others do.

Comment: I don't really understand what you're trying to get across. You should rely on yourself as much as you possibly can before asking others for help?  You can't count on anyone else like you can yourself? You need to believe in yourself before others will? Both "support" and "first" could mean a lot of things in this context, so it's hard to suggest an alternative.

Comment: "First supporter" sounds pretty strange to me. It sounds like a semi-official title or technical term, reminiscent of "first responder." I'd say "biggest supporter" instead. First means the one that came before others, but doesn't necessarily mean most significant or important.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your first sentence is not grammatical English, so it will not sound natural to any native speaker. The reason is that 'self' is the indirect object of first supporter, but your sentence doesn't indicate the relationship. You would have to say

> You are your own first supporter

Your second sentence fixes this problem by explaining that you are the first supporter of yourself. There is functionally no difference between 'your self' and 'yourself' in this case. They mean the same thing.

But neither sentence can be used by itself without sounding strange, because the phrase 'first supporter' is not a common phrase in native English. It's confusing because we don't know what is meant by the word 'first'. Does it mean you are the earliest one, the one that comes before the others sequentially? Or does it mean you're the most important one of all your supporters?

Also, the word 'supporter' is not usually used in a general way. It needs a context. A person might have supporters at work, or political supporters, but not just 'supporters'.

Your question says that you want to say a person 'should be' the first supporter of their self, but your suggestions use the verb 'are'. 'Are' doesn't mean the same as 'should be'. If you want to say that someone 'should be' their own supporter then use an imperative word like 'be'.

> Be your own first supporter

The idiomatic phrase that comes to my mind for saying the same thing is

> Be your own best friend

You could also say

> Support yourself first

This could be understood in several ways, depending on what the word 'first' is referring to. You would have to clarify what 'first' means by adding context.

> support yourself before you support others
>   support yourself before you do something else
>   support yourself before others support you

Comment: You mentioned that my second example goes with the preposition **of**, so does that mean **for** is incorrect? What I mean by "first" is as in your last suggestion, which is in other words: _You should be the first one to support yourself before expecting others to support you._ And I actually want the supporting matter to be in general.

Comment: Yeah, I came to the question just to see what was meant.  Doesn’t make sense.

Comment: @TasneemZH I wouldn't say 'for' is incorrect, but people normally say 'supporter of somebody or something' or 'support for somebody or something'. You can also say 'I"m here in support of...', or 'I'm doing this in support of...'. The way you said it in your comment sounds completely natural. Here you've used 'support' as a verb, which sounds fine used in general terms. There's an aphorism from Greek myth that we use to say something similar: 'The gods help him who helps himself'.

Answer (score 20):

> 3. "You are your own biggest fan."

This would be an informal way of saying the same thing. It could be used positively or negatively. If used in a negative sense, it is stating sarcastically that the person thinks too much of himself.

Here's a link to an Internet search showing how similar sayings are used in a self-affirming sense: [Link to search results](https://www.bing.com/search?q=you%20are%20your%20own%20biggest%20fan&qs=PF&cvid=caf04e4c007a4d0aad90e63202c126de&refig=5667d88f4fe247f4dc0b7c3442807486&cc=US&setlang=en-US&elv=AXK1c4IvZoNqPoPnS!QRLOPfgL*ij*jcxsohg7z1eRn4CuR7gVPhydzEz430Zd8!O1Ds!KiN54OQuRXkVj0QQ!YapMV0r94NQxcrm8roDd5A&plvar=0&first=11&FORM=PERE)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but would "fan" mean "supporter" literally?

Comment: @TasneemZH -- Yes.  Collins' dictionary lists this meaning as its first definition of "[fan](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/fan)".  I don't think this meaning was the original meaning of the word, though.

Comment: 'Fan' usually means a supporter of somebody famous, like a performer or athlete, or a supporter of an athletic team. It can be used for something a person is interested in, like 'I'm a fan of movies'.

Comment: @TasneemZH "Fan" is short for "fanatic," which is word that describes a very strong supporter. These days, fanatic usually has a negative connotation, but fan does not.

Comment: I believe the OP means "supporter" in the sense of a provider of support, such as a parent, friend, or mentor. I wish I could think of a noun to suggest that would convey this concept more clearly.

Comment: This is the best translation of the intended meaning of the original statement, in my opinion.  Direct translations of idioms rarely work, but there is usually a corresponding one available such as in this case.
The only potential issue is if the OP meant 'supporter' to be more 'assistant' than 'fan', in which case the corresponding idiom may be more like "The world helps those who help themselves"

Answer (score 14):

Statements like this typically use *your own X*:

> 5. You are your own first supporter.

This:

> 1. You are your self first supporter

sounds awkward.  *Self* is not used as a modifier very often except as part of fixed phrases like *self service*.

Comment: Such a great suggestion! Thank you.

Comment: Downvoted because I think this suggestion still sounds awkward. I can't imagine a native speaker *ever* saying this. First Supporter sounds like the name of a cop show or something, lol.

Comment: I believe the OP is not using _self_ as a modifier, but is rather trying to say "yourself's". Now if only there was such a construct...

Comment: @MrLister There is: "your own".

Comment: @wizzwizz4 Which was mentioned in Lawrence's answer, so I didn't need to mention it again.

Answer (score 12):

Here is a [rhetorical question](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/rhetorical-question) that makes the original poster's point:

> 4. If you don't believe in yourself, who will?

Comment: By numbering the examples, you are a genius. Thanks for your answer. (Did I phrase it correctly by the way?)

Comment: @TasneemZH -- Your comment would make a good question.

Comment: If that's the case, then I will save it for another time.

Comment: I have asked it [here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/204473/by-doing-something-you-are-something-is-the-structure-correct).

Answer (score 3):

Maybe something as simple as (this is very common)

> Believe in yourself.

A popular proverb is

> The Lord helps those who help themselves.

It is sometimes said that

> You can't find love until you love yourself.

Or if you want something a bit more pessimistic:

> The only person you can rely on is you/yourself.

Comment: Very nice proverbs; thanks. But isn't there something that includes the word "support" explicitly? Or could that "believe in" has the same meaning as "support"?

Comment: "Believe in yourself" means be confident, think highly of yourself and your potential.

Comment: Not quite the meaning I want to convey... But I appreciate it nonetheless.

Answer (score 2):

To capture what I think you are trying to emphasize, I would say:

`You yourself are your own first supporter.`

Answer (score 1):

The only way I'd use *self* in such a sentence is this: *Your first supporter is yourself.*  As others have said, *your own supporter* is more usual.

Answer (score -1):

What is a more proper way to say, “You are your self first supporter”?

"self first" uses two words to modify "supporter."  The words must be grouped by using quotation marks.  (Most, if not all, compound adjectives are grouped by using a hyphen.)

> You are your "self first" supporter.

I've found that making a sentence simpler works best.  In your case, try:

> I support myself first.

or

> Tom supports himself first.

etc.

Comment: Your first suggestion (with quotation marks) sounds totally unnatural and wrong. "Self first" isn't really a meaningful adjectival phrase.

Comment: This is the same as what _Grammarly_ suggests. I didn't go with its suggestion as I found the sentence odd. As for `I support myself first`, I think it is reasonable and correct, but I want it to sound a bit more idiomatic as a way of encouraging others to support themselves rather than stating that plainly.

Comment: @V2Blast You're correct, if I was using "self first" as an adjective phrase.  I was trying to use it to indicate that I was quoting the OP and that I was using the same wording.  You could also take the quoted segment to mean that I was describing a concept whose wording was kept together by quotes.  Anyway, you put together a good reply.