# "By doing [something], you are [something]." - Is the structure correct?

Tags: sentence-structure

I have phrased the sentence below awkwardly, I assume:

> By numbering the examples, you are a genius.

I want to know how it can be fixed to fit a proper and clear structure. And I suppose it would be more natural if it was stated like this:

> You are a genius by numbering the examples.

I think of that structure as if-statements but when they actually happen, not if they were to happen, like:

> If you numbered the example, you would be a genius.

Also, would "consider" fit in the sentence?

> By numbering the examples, you are considered a genius.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with any of the sentences you wrote, maybe a little bit more context should show the difference in each sentence?

Comment: If that was true, then @Jasper would have said a simple "yes".

Comment: You just edited the question. Now I get it, you want to know whether one of your phrases is more natural than the other.

Comment: Your second example should be fine. "by numbering the examples, you are a genius"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's certainly a valid sentence structure of the form "by [verbA] you [verbB]". It can use other prepositions, as well, such as *in* or *through*.

However, your first example is not natural. It doesn't work. I *think* that's because the first verb is an **action verb**, while the second is a **stative verb**.

The way to say that a person is shown to be a genius by showing the examples is to actually use words that *mean* that:

> By numbering the examples you are shown to be a genius.
>   By numbering the examples you show your genius.
>   In numbering the examples you prove that you are a genius.

If you wanted to say that number the examples actually caused them to be, or become, a genius, you want use *become*:

> By numbering the examples you become a genius.

For an example where both are stative:

> In knowing all prime numbers less than 1,000,000, you are a genius.

But not, although it is less awkward than your example:

> In knowing all prime numbers less than 1,000,000, you become a genius.

This is less awkward, and I'm not 100% sure why... perhaps the first half can be stative and the second half action, but not vice versa. However, this is not awkward:

> By learning all prime numbers less than 1,000,000, you become a genius.

More confidence about what sounds awkward is likely to come with *practice*, rather than learning *rules*. English is rather lacking in consistent general rules.

Comment: Thank you very much. In example #3, is it "... the prove" or "... that prove"? If it is the latter, then is it possible for the second "that" to be omitted? Also, can I substitute "become" with "are considered"? (as to not give the indication that the person was not very intelligent but now s/he is)

Comment: @TasneemZH Sorry, *the* was a typo for *you*. The *that* is optional in any case, though I would consider it more formal to use it.

Answer (score 2):

Although it feels awkward and I wouldn't use it, I believe that "By numbering the examples, you are a genius" is technically correct. An example that doesn't feel as awkward is "By reading this book, you are on a path to..."

For a less awkward-feeling sentence, I would say something along the lines of "By numbering the examples, you have demonstrated your genius."